# Search Bar in navigation bar when clicked on icon

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have put a table view in a view controller containing a list of items.

[In that i had put one search icon in navigation bar shown in first image.When i click on that icon a search bar opens and a cancel button will be shown.Cancel button is working.[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WIse.png)

Now i want to do search in search box.Please anyone can help me to get the code for that.

---

**In viewDidLoad:**

```
UIBarButtonItem *searchButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:@selector(toggleSearch:)];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchButton;
```

**toggleSearch:**

```
- (IBAction)toggleSearch:(id)sender
{

    _searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    _searchBar.delegate=self;
    [_searchBar sizeToFit];

    searchController= [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:self];
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    searchController.delegate = self;

    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar;

  searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;

}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement searchbar delegate methods.

First you can assign your main array to temporary array and after that  you can add this code.

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
[_searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
return YES;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
NSPredicate *result=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@",searchText];
NSArray * array = [arrTemp filteredArrayUsingPredicate:result];
arrMain=[array mutableCopy];
[tblview reloadData];
}

-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
[_searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
}

-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
NSPredicate *result=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@",searchBar.text];
NSArray * array = [arrTemp filteredArrayUsingPredicate:result];
arrMain=[array mutableCopy];
[tblview reloadData];
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];
[_searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
}
```